# Activity's UI freezes on AsyncTask's onPostExecute?

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I used `AsyncTask` to request for a large chunk of data. When received, the data is processed inside the `onPostExecute` method. It may take a while to process the data.

Based from my understanding, `AsyncTask` is asynchronous and is independent from the UI.

- Why does my Activity freezes `onPostExecute`?
- Is it normal for an `Activity` to freeze if processing inside the `onPostExecute` method is too long?
- How do I make it such that my `Activity` won't freeze `onPostExecute`?

Comment: is there in other long running task in onPostexecute ?

Comment: @ankitmakwana: Yes, but `onPostExecute` is part of `AsyncTask`. And if `AsyncTask` is asynchronous, having a long process inside `onPostExecute` should not make the Activity freeze since it runs on a separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should do all your datasource operations like(database , network ,parsing the response.etc) in `doInBackground` method.
2. If you want update any ui updation in async task the use `onProgressUpdate`
3. I think you are performing any parsing operations in `onPostExecute`. try getting filtered or parsed data (lighter data) in `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 1):

Why does my Activity freezes onPostExecute?

> According your post, you perform some time consuming operation on
>   PostExecute method. On PostExecute is running on UI thread, so it's
>   okay that you UI is freezed.

Is it normal for an Activity to freeze if processing inside the onPostExecute method is too long?

> Yes, it's. You should perform long operation in doInBackground method
>   (non-UI thread)

How do I make it such that my Activity won't freeze onPostExecute?

> Try to transfer your long time operation to doInBackground method and
>   in PostExecute just update UI according response, which you get after
>   operations in doInBackground method.

Comment: Could you please explain why putting a long process inside `onPostExecute` can cause the screen to freeze? It's because I thought `onPostExecute` is asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks @Nickolai! I wanted to check your answer but Gani's gave me the solution to my problem which is to put the long running task inside `onProgressUpdate`. I'm making a UI update so I can't put my code inside `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `doInBackground` method in your `AsynTask` method.

Comment: Move your Long operation in  doInBackground method.

Answer (score 0):

see Long Running Task You Need to Bind in `doInBackground`  here you cannot Bind UI control Like `Button`, `ImageView`  etc. After completion of  `doInBackground`  in `onPostExecute`  you can Bind All Require Control,  make sure here[`onPostExecute`] you  not runnning Another task.